# Retrieving SharedPreferences Data Failure

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to use SharedPreferences, but I keep encountering the following problem.

In the class where I create the file & add information to it I do the following:

```
private SharedPreferences prefs         = null;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;

public void setStuff (String info, boolean save, Context appCT) {
  if (prefs == null && editor == null) {
    prefs  = appCT.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();
  }
  editor.putString("Custom", info);
  editor.commit();
}
```

Which, to my knowledge, runs perfectly. However, when I attempt to access that information I stored in 'preferences' from another other class:

```
private static SharedPreferences prefs = null;
private static String custom = null;

public static void getStuff(Context appCT) {
  if (prefs == null) {
    prefs = appCT.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    custom = prefs.getString("Custom", null);
  }
}
```

The value of custom is always null, as if I never stored the String. Can anyone tell me why this is?

I have searched for an answer; I am using a context for getSharedPreferences, I have following all of the instructions & tutorials I have found with no varying results.

NOTE: The classes are not in the same application. Is this a problem? Can I not access the preferences of another application?

Thank you.

Comment: Ensure 'info' isn't null when saving. Ensure they are on same process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getStuff()` only sets `custom` if `prefs` is `null`. So, the method will do nothing after the first time it is called. Or, if `prefs` is set *before* this method is ever called, then the method will never do anything.

The method should look like this, instead:

```
public static void getStuff(Context appCT) {
  if (prefs == null) {
    prefs = appCT.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  }
  custom = prefs.getString("Custom", null);
}
```

Also, if the 2 classes are in different applications, `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` will prevent them from sharing the SharedPreferences. You can use [Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) or [Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) instead, but that is very unsafe and deprecated in API level 17. See the information at the above links to see what is recommended instead.

Comment: I did this, but I am still getting null every time. The reason I did it the previous way is because I only needed it to work once, the first time in which I knew that the preferences would be null. When debugging I see that prefs shows a file under mFile tab that is the location to the proper file, but when retrieving the value it is failing.

Comment: I assume that: (1) these two classes are in the same app, (2) you are calling setStuff() *before* getStuff(), and (3) you are passing a non-null 'info' String to setStuff()?

Comment: In reply to your good points: (1) They actually aren't in the same application. Is there a way to access one applications saved preferences from another? (2) That isn't really an issue because there will always be something in the file for it to retrieve. (3) Yes I added that check in, but it would never be null.

Comment: See my updated answer. You should probably use a different mechanism (ContentProvider or BroadcastReceiver) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need do to a prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(yourcontext); first.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. I tried using that instead of the current prefs assignment, I still get null. Using it outside of the if statement does not help me, and eliminating the if statement leads to two assignments of prefs, which seems silly to me. I guess I'm not understanding what you mean?